# Running client-side code after ASP ChangePassword control has finished

Tags: asp.net, popup, devexpress, change-password

I've got a .net ChangePassword control inside a DevExpress ASPxPopupControl. I'd like to automatically close the Popup window after the password has been successfully changed - however, I can't see any client-side controls that allow me to hook a `popup.Hide()` to the Continue button. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1):

If the Continue button is an AspxButton, use the below Code. **You need to make sure the ClientInstanceName of the PopupControl is set to "popup"**

```
 <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e){
    popup.Hide();
 }" />
```

Comment: It's not an ASPxButton unfortunately, it's the standard button that appears on the ChangePassword control - not one I have added myself or (it seems) have any control over.